# How to concatinate sting in Acumatica report Variable

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to concatenate lot serial number in a custom report to show serial number sold for an  item. I have declared a variable in detail section to concatenate the lot serial number but it always comes blank.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the expression editor, use **Functions > Text > Concat(str1, str2, ...)**.
Your formula should be:

```
=Concat($LotSerial,[SOShipLine.LotSerialNbr],', ' )
```